# Discord bot ignore all webhooks?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot that uses a leveling system. It listens to `message.author.id`, logs the latest message, gives the user XP and at certain levels, users are awarded a new role. Have been working fine for months.

Recently I added a few(10 to be exact) webhooks to the server to enable users to send in bug reports.
Problem is that my bot is reading those webhooks messages as well, and webhooks don't have an author ID, hence, bot crash every time a webhook is posting something.

I know we can except certain webhooks like this `if (message.webhookID != 'X') return;`
but its kinda inconvenient since I might add or delete webhooks in the future. Is there a way to make my bot ignore all webhooks similar to how it can ignore other bots?

**EDIT**
This is what I did,

```
client.on('message', (message) => {

//Check if its a webhook.
if (message.webhookID) {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition is false

  if (message.guild.id != '335008833267040256')return;{
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do `if (message.webhookID) return;`, that should return if the message is sent from *any* webhook.

Comment: Oh, how could I not have thought about that? That fixed my issue, cheers mate!

Comment: trying to figure out how to do this with COGs in python 